# Error when changing character set in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm trying to change a field in a mySQL database (ver. 5.6.45) from utf8 to utf8mb4 in order to be able to post emojis.

This is what I'm doing:

```
ALTER TABLE contenidos CHANGE COLUMN titulo varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

But I also tried (with the same result), this:

```
ALTER TABLE contenidos CHANGE COLUMN titulo CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE contenidos CHANGE COLUMN titulo varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

I keep getting this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci' at line 3

If I change trhe collation from phpmyadmin I can do it, but it doesn't seem to work, because the emojis are not saver in the database. So I thought that I should change the charset aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Review the syntax for ALTER TABLE here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

If you use CHANGE COLUMN, you follow that with the current name of the column, *then you must name the column again,* even if you are not changing the name.

```
ALTER TABLE contenidos CHANGE COLUMN titulo 
  titulo varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

The reason is that CHANGE COLUMN allows you to change the column name. If you wanted to do that, you'd name the column you want to change, then the new name.

```
ALTER TABLE contenidos CHANGE COLUMN <old_name> <new_name> <data-type> ...
```

The syntax for CHANGE COLUMN requires that you give two names, even if they are the same.

Alternative: use MODIFY COLUMN, which does not allow a column name change, but allows changes to other column attributes, including the character set. So you only need to list the column name once.

```
ALTER TABLE contenidos MODIFY COLUMN titulo 
  varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

By the way, each collation applies only to one character set, so you don't need to specify both. By specifying the collation, this will implicitly change the character set if necessary.

```
ALTER TABLE contenidos MODIFY COLUMN titulo 
  varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```